# Angular2: Dynamic style two color div on the basis of HTML table column values ratio percentage

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Greetings Generous Helpers. 
I;m very naive to angular2, I do have requirement, where I need to display ( two colored) div. as ratio-percentage difference between city Incoming\Outgoing calls data. On the basis of difference between two HTML table column values..
We have table something like..

**City**  |   **Incoming Calls**   |    **Outgoing Calls**   |    **Ratio In\Out calls**

**New York**     |          **4500**  |       **5600**  |   **divs two colored bar- red\blue** -- which will display the ratio % difference In\out call values ie 4500 and 5600

**Boston**     |       **8800**      |            **1200**    |     **divs two colored bar> red\blue** which will display the ratio % difference In\out call values ie 8800 and 1200

**LA**          |     **3400**       |          **8800**     |   **divs  two colored bar> red\blue** which will display the ratio % difference In\out call values ie 3400 and 8800

**Seattle**    |      **1200**       |          **790**    |   **divs two colored bar> red\blue** which will display the ratio % difference In\out call values ie 1200 and 790

sorry, if I'm not able to explain it clearly...I would be looking some thing .. like

```
.two-colour-bar { 
width: 60px; height: 10px; color: #fff; 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, orange, orange 30%, black 70%, black);
```

Here 30% , 70% will be changed as per input values(of table columns..of the table.. like ... 30% and 70% will depend on Incoming calls value (4500) and outgoing calls value (5600)

**City** | **Incoming Calls** | **Outgoing Calls** | **Ratio In\Out calls**

**New York** | **4500** | **5600** |

and above table is in *ngFor within table  inside HTML.. –

[sample look][1]

Comment: What does "ratio-percentage difference" mean exactly?

Comment: ratio between incoming and outgoing.. on the basis of table values.. means.. first need to calculate ratio between these two columns values.. then I need red and blue to show.. the table column values..

Comment: I don't get what the problem is. You want a formula how to calculate the ratio?

Comment: I guess I would be seeking how to handle this in angular2 and what should be ideal way to tackle the problem...
yes.. formula would also help...
after calculating this how to display the difference in multicolor divs...

Comment: What are "multicolor divs". The ratio is basic math. You don't need to add the `angular2` tag for that ;-).

Comment: sorry, if I'm not able to explain it clearly...I would be looking some thing .. like
.two-colour-bar {
    width: 60px;
    height: 10px;
    color: #fff;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, orange, orange 30%, black 70%, black);

But here 30% , 70% will be changed as per input values..of my table..
City          | Incoming Calls | Outgoing Calls | Ratio In\Out calls

New York |   4500 |                     5600 | 

and above table is in *ngFor within table <td> inside HTML..

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="fill" [style.width]="incoming / outgoing + '%'">

    </div>
  </div>
</td>

.progress {
  width: 200px;
  height:  20px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.progress .fill{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: sorry, if I'm not able to explain it clearly...I would be looking some thing .. like .two-colour-bar { width: 60px; height: 10px; color: #fff; background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, orange, orange 30%, black 70%, black); But here 30% , 70% will be changed as per input values..of my table.. 
City | Incoming Calls | Outgoing Calls | Ratio In\Out calls New York | 4500 | 5600 | and above table is in *ngFor within table <td> inside HTML.. –

Comment: above code will only show one color at a time.. rather. wil be looking something..
.two-colour-bar { 
width: 60px; height: 10px; color: #fff; 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, orange, orange 30%, black 70%, black);

Comment: any picture for explain?

Comment: Edit my answer.